# Strange libtool behaviour at link time

Tags: d, autotools, dynamic-linking, libtool

I'm currently trying to get Autotools to play nice with the D programming language. So far, I've had success with everything *except* dynamic libraries. I've written a [skeleton project](https://notabug.org/koz.ross/d-skeleton-lib) aiming to do this, but for some reason, after `configure && make`, I get the following error:

```
gdmd -m64 -inline -noboundscheck -g -property -w -wi -O -c -fPIC -ofsrc/foo.lo src/foo.d
/bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link   -g -O2 -version-info 0:1:0  -o libfoo-0.1.la -rpath /usr/local/lib src/foo.lo  
Usage: /home/koz/Documents/Programming/D/d-skeleton-lib/libtool [OPTION]... [MODE-ARG]...
Try 'libtool --help' for more information.
libtool:   error: unrecognised option: '-g'
Makefile:435: recipe for target 'libfoo-0.1.la' failed
make: *** [libfoo-0.1.la] Error 1
```

I'm not sure why those flags are being passed to libtool at link time - could someone please help me understand what's going on and how to avoid this behaviour?